# How does the multiplication in patterns work? (Python)

Tags: python

While trying to learn Python I do exercises and the one about repeating the following pattern seems quite difficult to comprehend.

Here's the pattern that you need to repeat with your code

1

2 2

3 3 3

4 4 4 4

5 5 5 5 5

6 6 6 6 6 6

7 7 7 7 7 7 7

8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8

9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9

The given solution is this:

```
for num in range(10):
    for i in range(num):
        print (num, end=" ")
    print("\n")
```

The tricky part for me is that looking at the given solution I do not see a part of code that is responsible for multiplying the ammount of numbers with each line (like number 5 repeats five times and number 7 repeats seven times in the line and so on). Could someone help me to grab the idea of the multiplication? Thank you in advance!

Comment: First off, please use 4 spaces for indentation, as this is the accepted community standard, defined in [PEP 8 -- The Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Whitespace is very important in Python, and it needs to be kept consistent. But, just as importantly, that code is wrong. It will print all the numbers in one long line, followed by a newline at the end. The `print("\n")` line needs to be indented one level.

Comment: Do you know what `range()` does?

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations @MattDMo
As far as I am aware range() returns a sequence of numbers

Comment: It might help to consider it repetition, not multiplication. The purpose of a loop is to repeat things. In this case there is a loop inside another loop, so the repetition is itself repeated

Comment: @Jess then why the number of repetition is equal the given number for each line? why doesn't it get repeated infinitely for example? and what part of the given code is responsible for the symbols' repetition?

Comment: The keyword `for` initialises a loop.
`for num in range(10)` literally means "for every number in the range 0 to 10"
so it repeats once for each number in that range - exactly 10 times

Comment: @MattDMo "But, just as importantly, that code is wrong. It will print all the numbers in one long line, followed by a newline at the end."
I tried to run the code and as a result the right sequense was there

Comment: The code you posted is wrong as @MattDMo described. Copy pasting to my computer and running it produces an error.
If it works on your machine you must have something slightly different.
Indentation - that is the empty space before a line of code, is very important in python

Comment: Indent the final `print` line 4 spaces from the left margin, so that it is aligned with `for i in range(num):`. Then it will run correctly.

Comment: @Jess "so it repeats once for each number in that range - exactly 10 times" . Yes, that's something that I do understand. I do not understand why there is one number 1 and seven numbers 7.

Comment: The nested loop `for i in range(num)` uses the `num` variable to decide how many times it will repeat. This means that when it gets to 7 it will go through the range 0 - 7 and print 7 exactly 7 times.

Comment: @Jess now I finally get it! Thank you very very much!:)

Comment: No problem, good luck learning!